# Python fastest container for booleans for index access

Tags: python, optimization, containers

I am looking for the fastest containers for accessing by index for the following function:

```
counter = 0

for i in range(large_integer):          
    for j in range(len(primes)):
        if patterns[j][i%primes[j]]: 
            counter +=1
            break
```

,where:
*large_integer* is greater than 10^10, 
*primes* is a 1D container with successive prime numbers. For example `(5,7)`
*patterns* is a 2D container that holds for each item in *primes* a 1D container of corresponding length that holds booleans. For example: `((False,True,False,True,False),(False,False,True,False,True,False,False))` 
*primes* is expected to have less than 50 numbers, all unique, each less than 100. After initial construction, none of the containers are expected to change.
So far the best I've come up are tuples. I've tried using numpy arrays, but they were about 2 times slower. I've also tried constructing the relevant booleans on the spot, without using the 2D container at all, but it was about 5 times slower.

---

Edit: For containers of this size, dictionaries with integer keys seem to be twice as fast.

Comment: Have you tried pandas? It's implemented more efficiently than python base types. Also I would recommend doing this kind of work in C. The attached script can generate 1,000,000 in just a few seconds where the equivalent in python struggles to generate a just few thousand primes in the same amount of time. https://gist.github.com/Krewn/6d04bfcb7eaf1e18afd88d129a206cb9

Comment: @kpie I think pandas can only be slower because it wraps around numpy arrays which the OP has already tried.

Comment: Good point, I think pandas is actually slower than np :/ my main point tho was that if speed is a major concern python is the wrong language.

Comment: @kpie generating primes is not a problem, since I'm not going to generate more than 50 primes anyway. And yes, I thought of doing it in C as the last resort - but I'm trying to bring it as far is possible in Python for now.

Comment: `pandas` and `numpy` aren't magic. They can significantly speed things up if you use vectorized operations on them, or performing linear algebra routines like matrix multiplication. However, using a double for-loop to access individual elements is going to be slow, and for arrays accessing individual elements is slow because the array has to do the equivalent of boxing.

Comment: You could try using a bitarray instead of a tuple of tuples of boolean but I havn't tried myself so I can't really speak to what you'll get for performance gains.

Comment: Maybe the array library would help? https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html